# Is it possible to delete a git repository online and if yes, how to avoid it?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I am sharing my Git repository (hosted on Bitbucket) with a contractor. To check the risk involved, someone asked me if the contractor can delete the repository history or delete it completely so we can not recover from it.

If there is such a possibility, how can I stop it to happen? I know that the contractor can push garbage data, but I can revert to an older commit and remove the garbage that he pushed.

But if he could manage to manipulate the history, then he can delete all good commits and publish some garbage commits and we can not recover the good commits.

I know that I can always have a copy of the repository on my local disk, but if I want to reply with an online copy and assume that I don't have a local copy, what would be the solution?

Comment: See [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver050/using-branch-permissions-913474668.html) and [that](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/using-repository-permissions-776639771.html).

Comment: I wouldn't give the contractor access to the original repository. Let them fork/clone it, and submit pull requests to be merged by you into the original.

Comment: Also know that you are on a hosted service: you can ask bitbucket customer support for a disaster recovery. But follow @chepner's advice as a base rule.

Comment: See the links that @dan1st posted. There's no need for him to fork the repo. You need to set branch and pull request permissions in BitBucket. You disallow developers from being able to manipulate the `main` or `master` branch, as well as `develop`. Only allow merges from `feature` branches to `develop` via a pull request. Then restrict that you have the only approval control for pull requests. Same for `main`, only allow merges from a `release` branch and only from you, using `git merge` or a pull request. (These branch names are related to using `git flow` for SDLC.)

Comment: I recommended the fork because I didn't recall what kind of permissions and restrictions Bitbucket provided, but the fork is generally applicable no matter where the repository is hosted.

Comment: @chepner This is not good, as I can only get access to one branch that he updates when we send a pull request to the original. I want to have and keep all history if possible.

Comment: Why do you care about history in his fork if it doesn't get merged into your original?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are the owner of that repository. You may ask him to create a branch and work on that branch. Ask the contractor to put Pull request for each feature.

Before merging into the master/main branch review the changes. Make sure reviewer's approval feature is turned on. When you'll find his commits are good to merge only then you'll merge it into the master/main branch. This won't let the contractor delete anything from the main/master branch.